# When I press submit nothing happen

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code, but when I press Submit nothing happen

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
  function Ctrl($scope) {
var str = $scope.text;
var ret = {};
for(x = 0, length = str.length; x < length; x++) {
  var l = str.charAt(x);
  ret[l] = (isNaN(ret[l]) ? 1 : ret[l] + 1);
}

for(key in ret) {
  alert(key + ' :: ' + ret[key]);
}
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="Ctrl">
```

You configure to angular execute the submit() function at the controller, but you don't have this function declared. You just need to create the `submit` function at the controller:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
   // Put you logic inside the method. 
}
```

I create a plunker with your code working:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ah2GV4FZpkCDxyqSAKXy?p=preview)